# How to create and use a QVector in other functions or is there an easier way to do this?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am using multiple QSpinBoxes that all need to do the exact same thing when interacted with. I am able to get them to do what I want with no issue but I thought I could optimize them by just having them call on 1 function. The only issue was that I would have to have an if statement in order to set a new minimum every time they are interacted with. If I could put them into some sort of array or list then I would be able to easily just make the change based off of one number. Using various previous threads and websites I tried to make a QVector of QSpinboxes in order to use as I previously described. After a lot of trial and errors I've reached a point where I'm not sure why I am getting the error that I am.

Here is my code:

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    QVector <QSpinBox*> boxes(0);
        
        QSpinBox* sqlBox=new QSpinBox(this);
        QSpinBox* perlBox=new QSpinBox(this);
        QSpinBox* rustBox=new QSpinBox(this);
        QSpinBox* cSharpBox=new QSpinBox(this);
        QSpinBox* htmlBox=new QSpinBox(this);
        QSpinBox* cssBox=new QSpinBox(this);
        QSpinBox* javaBox=new QSpinBox(this);
        QSpinBox* pythonBox=new QSpinBox(this);
        QSpinBox* cPlusBox=new QSpinBox(this);
    
        boxes.append(sqlBox);
        boxes.append(perlBox);
        boxes.append(rustBox);
        boxes.append(cSharpBox);
        boxes.append(htmlBox);
        boxes.append(cssBox);
        boxes.append(javaBox);
        boxes.append(pythonBox);
        boxes.append(cPlusBox);
    
    
    
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            boxes[i]->setRange(0, 1000);
            boxes[i]->accessibleName();
            
            if (i < 3)
            {
    
                boxes[i]->setGeometry(100, 105+(90*i), 71, 21);
            }
            else if (i >= 3 && i < 6)
            {
                boxes[i]->setGeometry(290, 105+(90*(i%3)), 71, 21);
            }
            else
            {
                boxes[i]->setGeometry(460, 105+(90*(i%3)), 71, 21);
            }
        }
    
    
    
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::buyPrgm(short unsigned int input,short unsigned int prgm)
{





    int first = 0, second = 0;
    first = revButton();
    if (code >= prgmCostOG[prgm] + pow(prgmCost[prgm], 0.1*prgmAmount[prgm]))
    {
        prgmAmount[prgm] = input;
        prgmCost[prgm] = prgmCostOG[prgm] + pow(prgmCost[prgm], 0.1*prgmAmount[prgm]);
        ui->boxes[prgm]->setMinimum(prgmAmount);
        
    }
    else
    {

        ui->noBuy->setText("You don't have enough code!");


        for(int i = 0; i > 1000; i++)
        {
            second = revButton();
            if ((second - first) > 5)
            {
                ui->noBuy->setText("");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The two errors I'm getting are:
"error: Member reference type 'QVector' (aka 'QList') is not a pointer; did you mean to use '.'? (fix available)"

```
// I can fix this error by changing
boxes[prgm]->setMinimum(prgmAmount[prgm]);
// into
boxes[prgm].setMinimum(prgmAmount[prgm]);
```

Even after making this fix I still have this error:
"error: No member named 'setMinimum' in 'QList'"
I assume this means that it only wants me to use the built in functions that work with QVectors for example "append' or "capacity" despite being able to use the built in functions for QSpinBoxes in the function that they were declared in.

Once again everything I've learned about QVectors has been through posts that people have already made so I may be making awful mistakes. Any help is welcome.

Comment: You are `new`ing a bunch of spinboxes in your destructor, and putting them in a local `QVector`, which is not the same container as `ui->boxes`. You really need to stop programming C++ by guesswork, because it is an unsafe language.

Comment: `prgmAmount[prgm] = input;` – if this *does* compile then `prgmAmount` *cannot* be an `int` as `pgrm` isn't an array either – so `ui->boxes[prgm]->setMinimum(prgmAmount);` *needs* to fail as `setMinimum` *does* expect an int. Cannot see where you want to apply the fix described.

Comment: Assuming you possibly wanted to create these spin boxes in a *constructor* instead then you can simplify construction creating the boxes inside the loop: `for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) { auto box = new QSpinBox(this); boxes.append(box); box->... /* apply what you need*/; } `.

Comment: Aside: look at putting your `QSpinBox`es into a `QGridLayout`, rather than specifying pixel locations for them.

Comment: why do you code and create all UI in the **destructor**?

Comment: @Parisa.H.R Any other widgets I have created before these QSpinBoxes I have done so using a drag and drop interactive system and so I had no idea where I was supposed to actually create the ui, I could not find anything explaining where I should have so that is just where I ended up putting it.